# Show a Wolfram Mathematica Plot from within Python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I need to show a plot created by the Wolfram Mathematica application used from within a Python script.

So far I have written the following code, but I do not know how I should show the information stored in the wlplot variable. Is it even possible in Python? The `plot.txt` file contains the command I need. I checked that the command is correct and that it is properly executed in the Wolfram Alpha itself.

```py
session = WolframLanguageSession()
plot_file = open("plot.txt")
wl_comm = plot_file.read()
plot_file.close()
wlplot = session.evaluate(wlexpr(wl_plot))
#???
session.terminate()
```

So the question is: If it is possible, what should I write within the Python script in order to show the plot created by the Wolfram Engine?

Comment: I don't use Mathematica but maybe you can save the plot to a PNG image and display that from Python simply enough. You might also state your OS, as the answer may be dependent on such things.

Comment: The command is saved in a *.txt file via a C application called from within the Python script. The whole idea is to combine the three applications in order to minimize the amount of button clicking. The OS is Windows 10.

I can easily use the Read command from Mathematica if I launch the application, so the command is correctly saved.

Comment: Is your comment above directed at me? I was suggesting you save a PNG file from Mathematica and then read that after Mathematica has finished. I didn't mention any text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working code follows.

```py
from PIL import Image

png_export = wl.Export(path,wlplot,"PNG")
session.evaluate(png_export)
img = Image.open(path)
img.show()
```